# Kafka 0.8.2.2 - Compact mode not work

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new beginner of kafka, i try to use COMPACT mode in kafka. 
   I look kafka document,  I think setting `log.cleaner.enable=true` and `log.cleanup.policy=compact` for COMPACT modem, but it seem not work. 
   Could you please help me. Thanks.

### environment

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Kafka kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2

### kafka config

- log.retention.ms=10000
- log.retention.check.interval.ms=1000
- log.cleaner.enable=true
- log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=1000
- log.cleaner.backoff.ms=1000
- log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.01
- log.cleanup.policy=compact

At kafka log, i see 'INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0], Starting  (kafka.log.LogCleaner)’, so i think success to enable COMPACT mode.

I follow QUICK START of kafka document, and input some data to test topic.

```
root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Sun Jan 10 14:23:26 UTC 2016

root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
[2016-01-10 14:23:38,312] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
22:23:45
22:24:05
22:25:00

root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Sun Jan 10 14:25:21 UTC 2016
root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic test --from-beginning --property print.key=true
null 22:23:45
null 22:24:05
null 22:25:00

root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Sun Jan 10 14:30:06 UTC 2016
root@50d8fe84c573:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic test --from-beginning --property print.key=true
null 22:23:45
null 22:24:05
null 22:25:00
```

I expect only keep on same key, so 22:23:45 and 22:24:05 message will be removed.

Thanks for morganw suggest. I have been push message of has key.

```
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic test --delete
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Wed Jan 13 01:21:59 UTC 2016
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# bpython3
from kafka import (
    KafkaClient, KeyedProducer,
    Murmur2Partitioner, RoundRobinPartitioner)
kafka = KafkaClient('localhost:9092')
producer = KeyedProducer(kafka)

>>> producer.send_messages(b'test', b'key', b'09:22:08')
[ProduceResponse(topic=b'test', partition=0, error=0, offset=0)]
>>> producer.send_messages(b'test', b'key', b'09:22:28')
[ProduceResponse(topic=b'test', partition=0, error=0, offset=1)]
>>> producer.send_messages(b'test', b'key', b'09:23:00')
[ProduceResponse(topic=b'test', partition=0, error=0, offset=2)]

root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Wed Jan 13 01:23:05 UTC 2016
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic test --from-beginning --property print.key=true
key 09:22:08
key 09:22:28
key 09:23:00
^CConsumed 3 messages
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# date
Wed Jan 13 01:27:18 UTC 2016
root@9d8bdae48429:~/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2# ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost --topic test --from-beginning --property print.key=true
key 09:22:08
key 09:22:28
key 09:23:00
```

But in result, the test topic still keep ALL message.

I don’t know i miss somehow. 
Could you please help me? Thanks. :-)

Comment: What is the expected use case when no key is provided? You seem to be assuming that any record with a null key is assumed to be the same record. Kafka may ignore records without a valid key. I've never used compaction, but you should probably do some research on null keyed records.

Comment: thanks for your suggest. i've been push message of exist key.
but it seem same result.

Comment: Have you defined the configs on the topic or on the broker?